# Default padding in layout created by Eclipse

Tags: android, android-layout

When creating a blank Android project in Eclipse, the newly created "Hello World" layout has a built in padding like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >
```

I couldn't find anything in Google design guidelines, also Google's own apps don't have such a padding. 
But I thought there has to be a reason why it is there. Any ideas?

Comment: For me instead of Linear-layout, Relative-Layout is coming.

Comment: I think it's just to encourage people to use Dimension types in their layouts http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is from Android guidelines, see [here](http://developer.android.com/design/style/metrics-grids.html#examples).